# React Native Parse Firestore Timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i realize there is absolutely 0 documentation on how to parse a firebase/firestore timestamp in react.

As it shows here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp

Timestamp in firebase is composed of seconds and miliseconds.

```
var newobj={
        uid_to:'K365J32fddel3QTxGG94VksXtQP2',
        uid_from:'RqVngIRyiJV2XTogLSONZIqoe5h1',
        monto:23,
        fecha:new Date(),
        user:{
            from_name:"fabri"
        },
        status:'pending'
    }
    firestore.collection('transacciones').add(newobj);
  }
```

Then in the console is showed as this

[image]

And when i do a query it brings this

```
Object {
  "fecha": Timestamp {
    "nanoseconds": 960000000,
    "seconds": 1526130923,
  },
  "monto": 23,
  "status": "pending",
  "uid_from": "RqVngIRyiJV2XTogLSONZIqoe5h1",
  "uid_to": "K365J32fddel3QTxGG94VksXtQP2",
  "user": Object {
    "from_name": "fabri",
  },
}
```

How do i parse it into a simple date, or datetime again?

Comment: How are you doing your query? Using the admin sdk, if I have a `DocumentSnapshot` object and do a `.get` on the fieldname, I get a standard Javascript `Date` object back. I guess you're probably not using the admin sdk in your react-native app, but I would assume the javascript libraries return fields for a given type the same way? Maybe not, and the documentation certainly isn't very clear on this front.

Comment: I have the same problem. What did you do?

Answer (score 16):

I struggled with this too and since I found no answers on SO or anywhere else, here's the solution that I got through trial and error. For sake of being complete here is how I saved the timestamp field to the articles collection:

```
saveArticle() {
  firebase.firestore().collection('articles').add({ 
    title: this.state.title,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  })
}
```

Then to display the date you need to call the object's toDate() method, convert that to a JavaScript Date object, then convert that to a date string. So in the render I have the below. Hope this saves someone some time.

```
<Text>{new Date(this.state.article.createdAt.toDate()).toDateString()}</Text>
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply call `.toDate()` on the firestore timestamp object to turn it into a JS date object.

So for you it would be something like `object.fecha.toDate()`. You can then use that to compare dates or use any other date method. You can also then pass it into moment.

You don't need to necessarily set the time with the `serverTimestamp()` method, using `new Date()` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by the following.
You can convert the date to string `dateObj.toString()` or `new Date().toString`.
Then when you receive that string back from fireStore simply convert it back to time like this `new Date(timeObjReceivedFromFireStore)`.