# Can I add days to a Cloud Firestore server timestamp?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a React Native app that creates a coupon for a user that has a date created field as well as date expires in Firestore. The date expired is the date created plus some days (e.g 7)

Ideally I would like to use firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in my firebase function for the created plus add 7 days to this for the expiry to avoid having the user generate the date.

Is there a way for this to be done?

Comment: Hello, have you seen this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306698/react-native-parse-firestore-timestamp)? I think it may come in handy to accomplish what you are after. Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tell Firestore to write a server timestamp, it does precisely that: it writes the timestamp of the server. There is no way to specify an offset for this operation.

This means you have broadly two options:

1. Write the offset to a separate field in the same document. So you'd end up with two fields in the document: `createdAt` and `expiresInDays`.
2. Read back the server timestamp and update it. This is typically something you'd do in Cloud Functions, when the document gets created `functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context)`.

Answer (score 5):

was running to the same issue, and the following code seems to work.

```
 const expiresIn = 7200
 const createdAt = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate()
 createdAt.setSeconds(createdAt.getSeconds() + expiresIn);
 admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(createdAt)
```

Comment: And to for example get a date some days in the future you would use:
`const numberOfDays = 7;`

 `createdAt.setDate(createdAt.getDate() + numberOfDays);`